# How to add text and toggle button above listView in android?

Tags: android

i want to add some explanatory text and one toggle button on top of listView...i referred to answers of many similar questions and tried their code, but mine text and toggle button gets added on top of every item of listView

my activity_first_point.xml which contain listView is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"


 >  


     <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
    >
    </ListView>
   <TextView
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/textItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

    />

</LinearLayout>
```

my java code is as follows:

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity{

String[] values={"Owner","Passcode","Friends","Settings","Help"};
ListView l;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListView l;
    l=getListView();
    l.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(8,0,0));

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,R.layout.activity_first_point,R.id.textItem,values));
```

Comment: ListView.addHeader(YOURVIEW);

Comment: create a custom listview: http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be adding your view (The view which having toggle button and textview) above your list item, custom cell. Instead of doing that, you can add it in header of your listview like,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
yourListView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

Here, `R.layout.headerView` is xml file which contains textview and togglebutton. And you can access it by:

```
TextView yourText = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```